# Subquery not returning proper results T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Subquery that is not returning the results I am looking for.  In the last Subquery, I have 3 Parts that do not have an Order Count for the date range in my condition and they are not returning with a result of 0.  Instead I am losing all the other data for those parts.  I'm sure there is a better way of querying the data, so here is my query.

```
    SELECT b.Part, b.Last_12_Mo, b.Last_6_Mo,
       COUNT(sd.SBINV) AS Order_Count
  FROM (
        SELECT a.Part, a.Last_12_Mo,
               ISNULL(SUM(sd.SBQSHP), 0) AS Last_6_Mo
          FROM (
                SELECT t3.Part, ISNULL(SUM(sd.SBQSHP),0) AS Last_12_Mo
                  FROM Top300 AS t3
                  LEFT JOIN SalesData AS sd 
                    ON t3.Part   = sd.SBITEM
                   AND sd.SBINDT > '20120315'
                 GROUP BY t3.Part, sd.SBLOC
                ) AS a 
          LEFT JOIN SalesData AS sd
            ON a.Part       = sd.SBITEM
           AND sd.SBINDT    > '20121015'
         GROUP BY a.Part, a.Last_12_Mo
        ) AS b 
  LEFT JOIN SalesData AS sd
    ON b.Part       = sd.SBITEM
   AND sd.SBINDT    > '20130110'
 GROUP BY b.Part, b.Last_12_Mo, b.Last_6_Mo
 ORDER BY b.Part
```

Comment: It would help to post the table create statements, sample data, and desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.  This should do it.

- Since you always want all items in Top300 regardless of their Sales data, you always have to keep the results of each subquery on the LEFT side of the LEFT JOINs.
- You can resolve the NULL SUM aggregates to zero
- The date filters need to be in the JOINs since you don't want to limit the Top300 items that do not join up.  If you put them in the WHERE clause, then it will exclude the Top300 items that do not join up with the sales data since the dates for those records would be NULL.

First setup the test tables and data

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('Top300', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Top300;
    GO
    IF OBJECT_ID('SalesData', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE SalesData;
    GO
    CREATE TABLE Top300 (
        Part  varchar(10)
    )
    GO
    CREATE TABLE SalesData (
        SBITEM  varchar(10)
       ,SBQSHP  int
       ,SBINV   int
       ,SBINDT  int
    )
    GO

    INSERT Top300
    SELECT A.*
      FROM (
            SELECT * FROM Top300 WHERE 1=2
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget1'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget2'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget3'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget4'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget5'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget6'
           ) A

    INSERT SalesData
    SELECT A.*
      FROM (
            SELECT * FROM SalesData WHERE 1=2
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget1', 100, 1000, '20120316'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget2', 100, 1000, '20120316'

            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget3', 100, 1000, '20121016'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget4', 100, 1000, '20121016'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Widget5', 100, 1000, '20121016'
           ) A
```

Now lets run a corrected version of the original query

```
    SELECT b.Part, b.Last_12_Mo, b.Last_6_Mo,
           COUNT(sd.SBINV) AS Order_Count
      FROM (
            SELECT a.Part, a.Last_12_Mo,
                   ISNULL(SUM(sd.SBQSHP), 0) AS Last_6_Mo
              FROM (
                    SELECT t3.Part, ISNULL(SUM(sd.SBQSHP),0) AS Last_12_Mo
                      FROM Top300 AS t3
                      LEFT JOIN SalesData AS sd 
                        ON t3.Part   = sd.SBITEM
                       AND sd.SBINDT > '20120315'
                     GROUP BY t3.Part
                    ) AS a 
              LEFT JOIN SalesData AS sd
                ON a.Part       = sd.SBITEM
               AND sd.SBINDT    > '20121015'
             GROUP BY a.Part, a.Last_12_Mo
            ) AS b 
      LEFT JOIN SalesData AS sd
        ON b.Part       = sd.SBITEM
       AND sd.SBINDT    > '20130110'
     GROUP BY b.Part, b.Last_12_Mo, b.Last_6_Mo
     ORDER BY b.Part
```

Finally, let's run a simpler, and more optimized query that produces the same results

```
    SELECT b.Part
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > '20120315' THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END) as [Last_12_Mo]
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > '20121015' THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END) as [Last_6_Mo]
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > '20130110' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [Order_Count]
      FROM Top300 b
      LEFT JOIN SalesData AS sd
        ON b.Part       = sd.SBITEM
       AND sd.SBINDT    > '20120315'
     GROUP BY b.Part
     ORDER BY b.Part
```

Comment: I needed to add the Location which is giving me the same problem as the sales.  Not all Locations have data in them.  How can I get those to show as 0 values?

Comment: You should be able to just follow the same pattern above with the location table.  Although, I would really need to see your "location" query, at a minimum, to understand your 2nd issue.  Try opening a new question with your "location" issue and provide some detail like the sales query above.

Comment: I pasted the "new" query that includes Location over my old one.

Comment: You really should put the old query back, so my answer above still makes sense.  Then take your new query and open a new question.  Then I can take a look at the new query and see about providing a solution.

Comment: Ok, I made the changes and posted a new question.